# Is there a monument or something related to Lars Ahlfors in Helsinki???

Tags: math-history

I’m right know in Helsinki and I would like to know if there is something I can visit which related to Lars Ahlfors or some other finnish mathematicians.

Comment: Well...there is the cemetery.

Comment: @DonAntonio well I should definetely check it out. I thought maybe there was something commemorating his fields medal

Comment: Find the user Jyrki Lahtonen somewhere on the site!

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen  help me please!!